# Is there any diffrence between Java language used in android programming and original J2SE

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I would like to know if there is any diffrence in the Java used in android programmming and standard java. This is because i have never heard about Intents ,etc in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NO difference, but some packages of java excluded from android
>   framework. Core java is used as language for Android development,
>   Android SDK provides API that uses JAVA to interact with ANDROID OS.

You can find list of java packages that is supported by android here [Java vs. Android APIs](http://www.zdnet.com/article/java-vs-android-apis/)

Comment: No difference, except something is missing and something extra is added. Also, code is not running in a JVM, but in [ART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime). Soooo..... *Different!!!!*

Answer (score 0):

Android uses Core Java as the language for programming. Its like a framework like Spring, Hibernate etc. . There are few basic components like Activity, Service, Broadcast receiver.

Intent is a simple message object which is used to communicate between components.

Answer (score 0):

In both logical programming style is same 
but you need to know few additional things in android. like basic components of Android. you can get everything in https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

happy android coding